# Creating database on odoo

Tags: macos, odoo, stack-overflow, helper

I am a second year software engineering student and right now i am doing my internship.
My mentor told me to download and install odoo15 on my device, which is MacBook Air.
I installed and ran it on my device and after a lot of errors finaly i got the screen of localhost:8069. In the screen I see 7 input options that are meant to create database and when i fill the inputs and create database, the datebase get created but i still stay at the same page and i can not log in into my account.
I don't know what to do.
Anyone here can help?

I Tried to create database and i was expecting after creating a database successfuly it would take to me to another page, where i could install some applications and continue learning odoo. But i didn't happen and i ended up creating several databases on my device

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of the browser page?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your Odoo config it's having `db_filter` option with a value different than the database name you have created and that could cause it to be invisible.

Just check to see if you have it, comment it and restart the service.
Also check for `db_name` but if you have `db_name` option it will automatically create the db for you and not always desired.

The default user and password for auto created databases it's `admin`

Comment: You could thanks me with upvoting and accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, your newly created datebase doesn't get selected. If that is the case you can go to http://localhost:8069/web/database/manager to select your database.